# Shadcn UI Navigation Menu can not add navigationMenuTriggerStyle

Tags: user-interface, next.js14

I am setting up a project with `NextJS 14` and `Shadcn UI`. I have just started the project with constructing the menu navgation.

https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/next : that is how I set `ShadCn UI`.

This is my nav component:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import {
  NavigationMenu,
  NavigationMenuContent,
  NavigationMenuIndicator,
  NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
  NavigationMenuViewport,
  navigationMenuTriggerStyle,
} from "@/components/ui/navigation-menu";

const MainNav = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationMenu>
      <NavigationMenuList>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <Link href="/" legacyBehavior passHref>
            <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
              Home
            </NavigationMenuLink>
          </Link>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger>Item One</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
            <ul className="grid w-[400px] gap-3 p-4 md:w-[500px] md:grid-cols-2 lg:w-[600px] ">
              <ListItem href="/docs" title="Introduction">
                Re-usable components built using Radix UI and Tailwind CSS
              </ListItem>
            </ul>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
      </NavigationMenuList>
    </NavigationMenu>
  );
};

export default MainNav;
```

And this is component from `Shadcn UI`:

```js
"use client"
import * as React from "react"
import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons"
import * as NavigationMenuPrimitive from "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu"
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

const NavigationMenu = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "relative z-10 flex max-w-max flex-1 items-center justify-center",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}
    <NavigationMenuViewport />
  </NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root>
))
NavigationMenu.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root.displayName

const NavigationMenuList = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.List>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.List>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.List
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "group flex flex-1 list-none items-center justify-center space-x-1",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
))
NavigationMenuList.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.List.displayName

const NavigationMenuItem = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Item

const navigationMenuTriggerStyle = cva(
  "group inline-flex h-9 w-max items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-background px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium transition-colors hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground focus:bg-accent focus:text-accent-foreground focus:outline-none disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 data-[active]:bg-accent/50 data-[state=open]:bg-accent/50"
)

const NavigationMenuTrigger = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(navigationMenuTriggerStyle(), "group", className)}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}{" "}
    <ChevronDownIcon
      className="relative top-[1px] ml-1 h-3 w-3 transition duration-300 group-data-[state=open]:rotate-180"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
  </NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger>
))
NavigationMenuTrigger.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger.displayName

const NavigationMenuContent = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "left-0 top-0 w-full data-[motion^=from-]:animate-in data-[motion^=to-]:animate-out data-[motion^=from-]:fade-in data-[motion^=to-]:fade-out data-[motion=from-end]:slide-in-from-right-52 data-[motion=from-start]:slide-in-from-left-52 data-[motion=to-end]:slide-out-to-right-52 data-[motion=to-start]:slide-out-to-left-52 md:absolute md:w-auto ",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
))
NavigationMenuContent.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content.displayName

const NavigationMenuLink = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Link

const NavigationMenuViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div className={cn("absolute left-0 top-full flex justify-center")}>
    <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport
      className={cn(
        "origin-top-center relative mt-1.5 h-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-height)] w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-90 md:w-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-width)]",
        className
      )}
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
))
NavigationMenuViewport.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport.displayName

const NavigationMenuIndicator = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "top-full z-[1] flex h-1.5 items-end justify-center overflow-hidden data-[state=visible]:animate-in data-[state=hidden]:animate-out data-[state=hidden]:fade-out data-[state=visible]:fade-in",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  >
    <div className="relative top-[60%] h-2 w-2 rotate-45 rounded-tl-sm bg-border shadow-md" />
  </NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator>
))
NavigationMenuIndicator.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator.displayName

export {
  navigationMenuTriggerStyle,
  NavigationMenu,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuContent,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuIndicator,
  NavigationMenuViewport,
}
```

This is the `Error` I get:

```
⨯ components/MainNav.tsx (22:69) @ navigationMenuTriggerStyle
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , _components_ui_navigation_menu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.navigationMenuTriggerStyle) is not a function
    at MainNav (./components/MainNav.tsx:28:130)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
  20 |         <NavigationMenuItem>
  21 |           <Link href="/" legacyBehavior passHref>
> 22 |             <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
     |                                                                     ^
  23 |               Home
  24 |             </NavigationMenuLink>
  25 |           </Link>
```

I could not find any information regarding this error.
All the `imports` and `exports` seem to be good and `navigationMenuTriggerStyle` is used as a function in the component without any errors.

How do I solve this? Or I have some stupid mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I found the fix
Just had to add 'use client' at the top of my nav component.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with this line. Conditionally passing an empty string as a value.

```
<NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()? navigationMenuTriggerStyle(): ""}>
```

try this out

```
<NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
```

Comment: I have placed this <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}> originally and the conditional was just me trying to find something working. I have updated the question